# remove anchor element around Wordpress images with filter (or jquery)

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I have an anchor element like this:

```
<a href="/link-to-image/" rel="attachment wp-att-7076"><img src="/uploads/img.jpg" alt="" title="" width="1268" height="377" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-7076" /></a>
```

(It's the standard way of Wordpress to embed uploaded pictures in a post.)

I want to remove the anchor around the image element, but keep the image. I simply want the image to show without being clickable.

This could be done either with a filter for the content of a post in Wordpress or after the page is loaded with javascript. Filtering in Wordpress would be preferred. I have no idea how to do either of those two options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into your WP theme's folder, edit "functions.php". Add code like this:

```
function remove_anchor($data)
{
    // the code for removing the anchor here

    // (not sure if you need help there, too).  

    // you will work on the $data string using DOM or regex
    // and then return it at the end


    return $data;
}

// then use WP's filter/hook system like this:
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_anchor');
```

The `add_filter` means that every time a post is displayed, the `remove_anchor` function is called.

jQuery is probably easier, you just need to identify the images and not make them clickable (this is untested)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#post a.some-class-name').click(function()
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you get a working version of this? Would love to see the full code. I just imported Blogger to WordPress and was able to convert external images to local copies, with a plugin, but they're still wrapped in anchors pointing to Blogger. Also, does this function actually update the database, so it can be removed after running once? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Find helpful code [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33724/remove-links-from-images-using-functions-php):

Tried out, but caused invalid code.

Your code in ../your_theme/**functions.php** would look like this:

```
function remove_anchor($content) {
    // the code for removing the anchor here
    $content =
        preg_replace(
            array('{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content\/uploads)[^>]*><img}', '{</a>}'),
            array('<img',''),
            $content
        );
    return $content;
}

// then use WP's filter/hook system like this:
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_anchor');
```